# Do I have to fix cracked grout right away or not?

Tags: shower, grout

I've got some cracked grout on my shower back walls. I'm a noob when it comes to home stuff. I'd like to find out if it's something that has to be fixed as soon as possible, or it's just more a cosmetic issue.

[image]

Since it's a back wall, I don't think much water can get in those cracks. I'd appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it has cracked, then there's some settling going on and the cracks will probably get worse. You'd be amazed at how much moisture can get through those "back walls". That moisture can deteriorate drywall and green board. I'd be fixing that soon. There are epoxy grouts out there that are much stronger than standard grout. You might want to look into that.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you tell me what can be a reason for those cracks ?

Comment: I have seen grout crack because the walls have settled a bit. I've seen grout crack because it dried too fast and wasn't kept moist like most directions say to do. I've seen it crack because the grout had started to harden before being applied.

Comment: I'm sorry but I've got another question. Can I use something like Aqua Mix Sealer's Choice Gold   to deal with those cracks, or grout has to be replaced in this case?

Comment: @Noob   Sealers will soak into the grout and prevent moisture from being absorbed due to the grout being porous but sealers won't fix/fill cracks. I would repair the cracked grout. Before you know it, it'll crack wider  and then you'll have water intrusion.

Answer (score 4):

**Grout is not meant to be a water barrier**!

Grout is porous. If the cracks are surface grout cracks only, then repairing the grout for cosmetic reasons makes sense. If the underlying water barrier (there are various types) is compromised then repairing just the grout will not stop water intrusion.

Comment: Epoxy grouts are water proof and often used in these scenarios (pretty sure it's a requirement for wet areas where I live). I'd still be fixing it ASAP regardless of whether its intended as a moisture barrier or not.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm still trying to understand what to do in this case. I don't want to hire someone to replace all grout since it is slightly cracked in a couple of places. I was thinking maybe I could use Aqua Mix Sealer's Choice Gold as a sealer to deal with those cracks. Do you think it's something that can be used to deal with this issue?

Comment: I think that the cracked/spalled grout is due to impact on a weak wall and/or improper grout mix/slake. The waterproof membrane behind the tile would likely be able to flex with some movement and not be compromised. I think you should repair the grout and you will probably be fine, but keep an eye out for signs/symptoms of water penetration (discolored opposite wall/floor adjacent/below), especially considering the area described is splash exposed, not constant water exposure.